# PL/SQL Procedure with DBMS Output within Implicit Cursor Loop

Tags: loops, plsql, cursor, procedure, implicit

I am working on a homework assignment, which requires letter grade updates based on marks.  Both must be done with procedures.  The first using an implicit cursor and the second an explicit cursor.  My explicit cursor procedure works perfectly.  My implicit cursor has two issues however.  The first, it does not seem to update for a mark of 50.  The second, when displaying output it displays the student id but not the updated grade.  Any ideas for fixing these?  Following is what I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE comp_grade_s IS
  CURSOR cur_class IS
    SELECT studid, marks, grade
    FROM class
  FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;
  TYPE type_class IS RECORD
    (studid class.studid%TYPE,
    marks class.marks%TYPE,
    grade class.marks%TYPE);
  rec_class type_class;
  lv_grade_txt class.grade%TYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN cur_class;
  LOOP
    FETCH cur_class INTO rec_class;
      EXIT WHEN cur_class%NOTFOUND;
      UPDATE class
        SET grade = 'F'
        WHERE marks < 50;
      UPDATE class
        SET grade = 'D'
        WHERE marks >= 50 AND marks < 60;
      UPDATE class
        SET grade = 'C'
        WHERE marks >= 60 AND marks < 70;
      UPDATE class
        SET grade = 'B'
        WHERE marks >= 70 AND marks < 80;
      UPDATE class
        SET grade = 'A'
        WHERE marks >= 80;
      UPDATE class
        SET grade = lv_grade_txt
        WHERE CURRENT OF cur_class;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Student ID: ' || rec_class.studid || ' gets grade ' ||
        lv_grade_txt); 
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur_class;
END;
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance,
Emily

Answer (score 0):

try this one i don't know why are u not trying to print the grade in the dbms_output from the

record in which you have defined

create or replace PROCEDURE comp_grade_s IS

CURSOR cur_class IS

```
SELECT studid, marks, grade

FROM class
```

FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;

TYPE type_class IS RECORD

```
(studid class.studid%TYPE,

marks class.marks%TYPE,

grade class.grade%TYPE);
```

rec_class type_class;

BEGIN

OPEN cur_class;

LOOP

```
FETCH cur_class INTO rec_class;

  EXIT WHEN cur_class%NOTFOUND;

  UPDATE class

    SET grade = 'F'

    WHERE marks < 50;

  UPDATE class

    SET grade = 'D'

    WHERE marks >= 50 AND marks < 60;

  UPDATE class

    SET grade = 'C'

    WHERE marks >= 60 AND marks < 70;

  UPDATE class

    SET grade = 'B'

    WHERE marks >= 70 AND marks < 80;

  UPDATE class

    SET grade = 'A'

    WHERE marks >= 80;

  UPDATE class

    SET grade = lv_grade_txt

    WHERE CURRENT OF cur_class;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Student ID: ' || rec_class.studid || ' gets grade ' ||

    rec_class.grade);
```

END LOOP;

CLOSE cur_class;

END;